# Javascript Using .indexof to search through object and create a table.

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, indexof

I will first paste the code for this entire example, and then highlight where my question lies.
    var journal = [];

```
function addEntry(events, didITurnIntoASquirrel) {
  journal.push({
    events: events,
    squirrel: didITurnIntoASquirrel
  });
}

addEntry(["work", "touched tree", "pizza", "running",
      "television"], false);
addEntry(["work", "ice cream", "cauliflower", "lasagna",
      "touched tree", "brushed teeth"], false);
addEntry(["weekend", "cycling", "break", "peanuts",
      "beer"], true);

console.log(journal)
//Making calculate phi for different inputs.
    function phi(table) {
      return (table[3] * table[0] - table[2] * table[1]) /
      Math.sqrt((table[2] + table[3]) *
          (table[0] + table[1]) *
          (table[1] + table[3]) *
          (table[0] + table[2]));
 }


function hasEvent(event, entry) {
  return entry.events.indexOf(event) != -1;
}
```

I think I understand the entry.events.indexOf(event) piece but it is confusing why I can do entry.events, I know events is a property in journal, and to access the property I can use (.). So I can do events.indexOf(), but I don't see why I can do entry.events.indexOf(). How is events a property of entry?

```
function tableFor(event, journal) {
var table = [0, 0, 0, 0];
for (var i = 0; i < journal.length; i++) {
var entry = journal[i], index = 0;
if (hasEvent(event, entry)) index += 1;
if (entry.squirrel) index += 2;
table[index] += 1;
 }
return table;
 }

console.log(tableFor("pizza", JOURNAL));
// → [76, 9, 4, 1]
```

In tableFor, I understand that I have created a table template, 
I see that I am iterating through the journal, but I do not understand why I am setting the variable index = 0, then index += 1, and especially index += 2 when I find "squirrel" in my journal. I also don't understand what table[index] +=1 is doing. If table is an array does that mean it adds +1 to all indices in the array. ( [0,0,0,0] -> [1,1,1,1])? How does the command table[index] +=1 have access to all the indices within the table?

Also,

Does anybody have a suggestion on an example problem similar to this one, that tests similar concepts but it better written and provides a more clear explanation on how to access properties within objects? I am just starting to learn object oriented and this example is quite awful because the explanations are brief and don't run through the code.

Thank you!

Comment: Also I should note that

No Squirrel no pizza = 0,0
No squirrelm, yes pizza = 0,1
yes squirrel, no pizza = 1,0
yes squirrel, yes pizza = 1,1

Therefore when it does index +=1 for the condition that you have Pizza you are just shifting your cursor to the 0,1 spot. 
If you have pizza and you have squirrel you are shifting to the 1,1 spot.

So it is just moving to that spot, and then adding +1 with the command table[index] +=1 only at the (11) spot (for this conditon)?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot a scattered questions here, Jonathan. To answer the first, 'journal' is an Array of Entry objects, and each Entry object contains an Array of 'events'. These 'events' are String objects. The example is probably confusing because the Entry object is never given a variable name or explicitly defined anywhere. It's only represented as what is called an Anonymous object within the `addEntry()` function. In fact, I'm only referring to these objects under the name 'Entry' by virtue of the context of the method name. In the code, there is not any object officially called 'Entry' but only an Anonymous object (without any name) that contains the 'events' and 'squirrel' properties. The object is created on the fly and pushed into the journal array by the `addEntry()` function.

Now back to the question at hand...`events` is not a property in `journal`. `events` is a property of any 'Entry' object within the `journal` Array. When `hasEvent()` is called it is passed an 'Entry' object (under the variable name entry) and a particular event to look for within that Entry. So in the context of the function, using `entry.events` accesses the events array within the Entry object. Then a call to `.indexOf(event)` searches that array of events for the occurrence of a particular event. In this case it is performing String comparisons between the event string passed into the method and the Strings in the `events` array until it finds a match.

I'll wrap up by recommending some interactive JavaScript tutorials over at Codecademy. I'll provide a link to the main curriculum, but for the questions you have here in this post, I'll direct you to the 'Introduction to For Loops' lesson in Unit 3 as well as the 'Arrays and Objects' lesson in Unit 6. These are all free. I hope you find them to be helpful.

https://www.codecademy.com/learn/javascript

Best of luck in your learning!